# Intuitive functional analysis book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, big-list

I would like a functional analysis book like Terence Tao's *Real Analysis and Measure Theory* book, full of intuition. I am comfortable with concepts in linear algebra, real analysis, measure theory, and probability theory.

Comment: http://www.hindbook.com/index.php/functional-analysis

Comment: Kreyszig might be a good start..

Answer (score 4):

For intuition, I recommend [Principles of Functional Analysis](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=stGFAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=martin%20schechter&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAWoVChMIx6WYppmbxwIVBxqOCh0Gswdk#v=onepage&q=martin%20schechter&f=false) by Martin Schechter. If you are interested in PDEs, there is no book better than [Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=haim%20brezis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIvb31mZmbxwIVD3GOCh3jNAAm#v=onepage&q=haim%20brezis&f=false) by Haim Brezis.

You might also be interested in the Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics Series by Michael Reed and Barry Simon, in particular, the first volume on [Functional Analysis](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rpFTTjxOYpsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

As a contrast to these, read either [Conway](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=john%20conway&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwA2oVChMI2tuF0J2bxwIVDAaOCh3wqQYH#v=onepage&q=john%20conway&f=false) or [Rudin](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=l7XFfDmjp5IC&printsec=frontcover&dq=walter%20rudin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC0Q6AEwA2oVChMIiZvQ2J2bxwIVyI6OCh1opwgg#v=onepage&q=walter%20rudin&f=false) for clarity and economy of expression.